# Using 25% width is remove an element from the page

Tags: html, css

I was making a test website in my spare time and I was trying to make a menu bar. While I was making it I was going to have 4 options. So I used 25% width to correctly divide the page. I tested it on Google Chrome and I realized that when I used 25% with 4 options, it gave me 3 can removed the fourth from the page and left a large space.  I don't know what I am doing wrong and I would like some help.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><span id="title">Test</span><span     
id="com">.com</span></div>
<div id="linkheader"><ul id="menuul">
<li id="menuil1"><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li id="menuil2"><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li id="menuil3"><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li id="menuil4"><a href="">Test</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

#header {
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 68px;
padding-top: 20px;
line-height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
font-family: Arial;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #080808;
font-size: 1.25em;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#title {
color: #E00000;
font-size: 2.1875em;
}
#com {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 2.1875em;
}


#menuul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 4px;
display: inline;
}

#menuil1 {
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
#menuil2 {
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
#menuil3 {
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
#menuil4 {
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}

a {
display: inline;
width: 60px;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

a:visited { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

#linkheader {
height: 1.75em;
line-height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
font-family: Arial;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #080808;
font-size: 1.25em;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

For the width's if I do 24% on one of them it fits them all onto a page but if I do 25% on all it seems to not want to all fit onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to your `ul`.

```
#menuul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  display: block;
}
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

#header {
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 68px;
padding-top: 20px;
line-height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
font-family: Arial;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #080808;
font-size: 1.25em;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#title {
color: #E00000;
font-size: 2.1875em;
}
#com {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 2.1875em;
}


#menuul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 4px;
display: block;
}

#menuil1 {
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
#menuil2 {
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
#menuil3 {
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}
#menuil4 {
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 25%;
}

a {
display: inline;
width: 60px;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

a:visited { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

#linkheader {
height: 1.75em;
line-height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
font-family: Arial;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #080808;
font-size: 1.25em;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"><span id="title">Test</span><span     
id="com">.com</span></div>
<div id="linkheader"><ul id="menuul">
<li id="menuil1"><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li id="menuil2"><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li id="menuil3"><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li id="menuil4"><a href="">Test</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried your suggestion but it never seems to work. Here is a link to the image I see (again this is on Google chrome so that may be the issue.): https://gyazo.com/392797094f0bdcd8771106897e4a4054

Comment: Can you copy your code into jsfiddle so I can see the problem?

Comment: @jfoutch A js file? I can dropbox it if you would like.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2jg5duc0/ But on my web browser it doesn't show the 4th test. Shown in the linked image above.

Comment: Have you used the web inspector on your browser? Try setting margins and paddings to 0 on all containing elements and widths to 100%. Try removing the padding on the ul also or set column widths to 24% instead of 25

Comment: @jfoutch what you are suggesting is not needed. He shouldn't need to remove the `padding` on the `ul`, according to the code he supplied.

Comment: @Hawkeye I suspect there is something else going on. As you can see in the snippet I provided above; it works (I tested in Safari, Chrome and Firefox); I think there might be something on your live website we don't have access to here. Do you have a link to the website? Please provide all relevant styling and code

Comment: I'm basically guessing here because he was unable to recreate the problem. Good luck @hawkeye

Comment: @Quoid I am using localhost :P I don't have a person dev website. If that helps in anyway.

Comment: @Hawkeye unfortunately we don't have access to your local machine:( you have something else going on, or other stylesheets; as you can see from the examples linked, the issue is **not** present in the fiddle, so it is something specific to your project - as a side note, that is why it is important to create an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue yourself (rather than just pasting code) so you can verify all the necessary code is there and it properly demonstrates your issue - if you don't have the issue in a fiddle, but on your local machine, then you're forgetting code